# How to remove repetitive column entries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 column like this:

```
city_name       car_name

Gurgaon         Alto
Gurgaon         Mercedez Benz
Gurgaon         Swift Dzire
New Delhi       Alto
New Delhi       Etios
New Delhi       Mercedez Benz
New Delhi       Swift Dzire
```

I made this by running a query using `group by` tag, but my task is to display a table with non repetitive entries. I.e. I want to display my table something like this:

```
city_name       car_name

Gurgaon         Alto
                Mercedez Benz
                Swift Dzire
New Delhi       Alto
                Etios
                Mercedez Benz
                Swift Dzire
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Comment: Do that in your program logic and not in SQL

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` and then a check with `CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN city_name ELSE '' END`

Comment: can you give me a short example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done in a front end / reporting tool and not using sql. If you have no option, try this

```
select case when sno=1 then city_name else '' end as city_name,car_name from
(
select row_number() over (partition by city_name order by car_name) as sno, * from table
) as t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select city_name, (SELECT  [car_name]+','
    FROM [myTable] AS [t1]
    WHERE t1.[city_name] = t2.[city_name]
    FOR XML PATH('') ) AS cars
    FROM [MyTable] AS [t2]
GROUP BY [t2].[city_name]
```

You can replace the , (or any other string you might use) with newline character in your display medium.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
;with CTE as
(
select row_number() over (partition by city_name order by car_name) as rn, * from table
)

Update CTE
set city_name=' '
where rn > 1
```

Here you can update the same table. No Need to create temp table/intermidiate table.